# Error: Cannot find module 'tap' but it isn't a dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, tap

I get this error:

```
$ npm test                                                                                                    

> playWithParameters@1.0.0 test /home/durrantm/Dropnot/code/js/mochaChai/playWithParameters                   
> mocha **/*.test.*                                                                                           


Error: Cannot find module 'tap'                                                                               
Require stack:                                                                                                
- /home/durrantm/Dropnot/code/js/mochaChai/playWithParameters/node_modules/asn1/tst/ber/reader.test.js
```

but I don't have tap as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a dependency was added - Big - that has an error.
Even though the code stopped using it, this error remained because a devDependency is still listed as can be seen in `package.json`.

To fix this just do

```
npm remove big
```